# Symfony PHPUnit Bridge: Get specific list of deprecation notices

Tags: symfony, phpunit, drupal-8

Running PHPUnit with the Symfony PHPUnit Bridge listener gives me a yellow box "Legacy deprecation notices (10)" in a custom Drupal 8 module. I would like to fix those 10, but am struggling to get the details which they are (e.g. which line of code).

- I've read the [documentation on the Symfony PHPUnit Bridge](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/edit/4.0/components/phpunit_bridge.rst).
- I've added `--verbose` to the phpunit command line.
- I've set the  `SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER` environment variable to 0 or 1, both in Bash and in my [phpunit.xml](https://github.com/drupal/core/blob/8.6.x/phpunit.xml.dist).

I have the suspicion that something in my environment reverts my attempts to see details. Nothing seems to change the output.

Versions:
 - PHPUnit 4.8.36
 - Symfony PHPUnit Bridge 3.2.14
 - PHP 7.0.22

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

If you want more detail, you can try this:

```
export SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER="/.*/"
```

before launch phpunit.